# Rodapé não se posiciona no final da página

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-5

Meu css:

```
#rodape {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}

.RodapeFaleConosco {
    float:right;
}

.RodapeTermoPolitica {
    float: left;
}
```

Agora meu código no jquery para carregar o html

```
str += '<div id="rodape">';
                    str += '<div id="dvFaleConosco" class="RodapeFaleConosco">';
                    str += '<a href="../FaleConosco.aspx">';
                    str += '<img src="Images/btfaleconosco.jpg" border="0" /></a>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    str += '<div id="dvTermoPolitica" class="RodapeTermoPolitica">';
                    str += '<span class="HomeTextoDestaque" style="font-size: 10px; padding-left: 100px; text-align: center;">Virgula99';
                    str += '- 2013 - Todos os direitos reservados.</span>';
                    str += '</div>';
                    str += '</div>';

                    $('#rodapeGeral').html(str);
                    str = "";
```

Meu cshtml

```
<form id="formPesquisa"  method="post">
            <label>CNPJ:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtCnpjPesquisa" name="txtCnpjPesquisa" onkeypress=" return SomenteNumero(event);" placeholder="Digite um cnpj válido"/>
            <button id="btnPesquisarCnpj" name="btnPesquisarCnpj" class="btn-pesquisa" >Pesquisar</button>

            <div id="filtroPesquisa">

            </div>

        </form>

        <div id="rodapeGeral">

            </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="txtTipoStatus" value="" />
    </div>
```

Quando eu carrego uns textos, o rodapé fica no meio deles e não em baixo(rodapé).

Comment: Ajude a gente a te ajudar. poste o seu código em http://jsfiddle.net/ que assim podemos te ajudar.

Comment: Com os códigos que ele passou:
http://jsfiddle.net/NTbDA/

Comment: Pode completar o jsFiddle que está no comentário acima, para podermos ajudar melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Da forma que está não aparecerá informação alguma da div "rodape", pois está faltando a inicialização de "str" no seu código JS. Use 
`var str = ""` antes do `str += "<div…` ou use diretamente `str = "<div…` sem concatenar.

Answer (score 0):

Se bem entendi, você quer que o form(e os inputs) apareçam no fim do html, então adiciona isso no teu css:

```
body, html{width:100%; height:100%}
form{position:absolute; bottom:0 }
```

Answer (score -2):

coloca a tag clear:both; no seu css do rodapé.

Comment: Poderia aprofundar sobre como o `clear: both` resolveria o problema? Da forma como está, a pergunta fornece poucas informações sobre o que está ocorrendo de errado.